# Result of a function not appearing after clicking

Tags: angular, button, methods, angular-material, undefined

These days i've been working on a pokemon-based project.

My issue is that is that if i click on form's button, it didn't appear me any string with the randomly obtained attack between the four attacks that a pokemon has.

First i'll show you the template:

```
<div>
  <mat-card class="attack-form">
    <mat-card-header id="attacks">
      <mat-card-title class="h4">Random Attack Generator</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form id="form-attacks" [formGroup]="attacksForm" (ngSubmit)="generateRandomAttack()">
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Selecciona un entrenador</mat-label>
          <mat-select matNativeControl formControlName="trainerName" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let trainer of trainers" [value]="trainer.fullName">
              {{trainer.fullName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Selecciona un pokemon</mat-label>
          <mat-select matNativeControl formControlName="pokemonName" #matSelect>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons" [value]="pokemon.name">
              {{pokemon.name}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="rage == true" formControlName="lifeUnderFifty">Click if life is under 50%</mat-checkbox>
        <!-- <re-captcha class="re-captcha" formControlName="recaptcha" siteKey="6Lf2lRciAAAAAC6tIMOl7kPrHfv7yUdAGs0VCz_K"></re-captcha> -->
        <button type="submit" mat-raised-button [disabled]="!attacksForm.valid" >Generate random attack!</button>
      </form>
    </mat-card-content>
    <div class="randomAttack">
      <h2>Attack generated</h2>
      <p>{{ generateRandomAttack() }} </p>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Then i'm going to show the functions selectAttack(), getRandomStyleAttack() and getRandomAttack():

```
selectAttack(trainers: Trainer[], chosenTrainer: string, chosedPokemon: string, rage: boolean) {
  
    const trainer = trainers.find((trainer: Trainer) => trainer.fullName === chosenTrainer);

    const pokemon = trainer?.pokemons.find((pkm: Pokemon) => pkm.name === chosedPokemon);

    if(!pokemon) return undefined;

    const natureConfig = this.natureDicts.find((nature: NatureDictionaries) => nature.name === pokemon.nature);
  
    if (!natureConfig) return undefined;

    let natureValues;
    if (rage) {
      natureValues = {
        attackValue: natureConfig.rageAttVal,
        defenseValue: natureConfig.rageDefVal,
      };
    } else {
      natureValues = {
        attackValue: natureConfig.basicAttkVal,
        defenseValue: natureConfig.basicDefVal,
      };
    }
  
    const attackStyle = this.getRandomStyleAttack(natureValues);
  
    return this.getRandomAttack(pokemon, attackStyle);
  }

   getRandomStyleAttack(natureValues: any){
      var num=Math.random();
      let styleAttack;
      if(num < natureValues.attackValue) styleAttack = "Attack"; 
      else if(num < (natureValues.attackValue + natureValues.defenseValue)) styleAttack = "Defense"; 
      else styleAttack = "Support";

      console.log(styleAttack);

      return styleAttack;
  }


   getRandomAttack(pokemon: Pokemon, styleAttack: string){
      var attackList = pokemon.attacks;
      if(pokemon.attacks.some((atk: any) => atk.style == styleAttack)){        
          attackList = pokemon.attacks.filter(atk => atk.style == styleAttack);
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * attackList.length-1);
      }else{
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * attackList.length-1);
      }

      console.log(attackList[index]);

      return attackList[index].name;
  }
```

And finally, the call of the selectAttack() method on the controller's component.

```
generateRandomAttack(){
    // Proceed with assigning the value to this.randomAttack

    const attack = this.attackService.selectAttack(this.trainers, this.trainerName, this.pokemonName, this.rage);
    if (typeof attack === 'string') {
      this.randomAttack = attack;
    }

    return this.randomAttack;
  }
```

How could you fix this issue in order to show a string when i click on the form's button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not put functions in bindings. `<p>{{ generateRandomAttack() }} </p>` this will evaluate every time the template is rendered and it depends on component state which might not even be initialized on first render.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called "randomAttack" that is generated on form submit

I believe this should work:

- You have to add a *ngIf that checks if randomAttack is undefined or not. This will display the generated attack's block, like so `<div *ngIf="randomAttack" class="randomAttack">`
- Instead of trying to show your attack using `<p>{{ generateRandomAttack() }}</p>`, try to use your component variable, like so: `<p>{{ randomAttack }}</p>`